# Question I got while building an Instagram clone DB on MySQL as an absolute beginner

Tags: sql, mysql

I just came into IT and I'm learning MySQL from a course on Udemy by Colt Steele. I was building a mini Instagram clone DB and I was stuck with a doubt.

An `id` was created in the `users` table as shown below. And a `photos` table was created, which had an id for the photos (`photos.id`). And ANOTHER variable called `user_id` was created in photos table, which was referenced as a foreign key to `users.id` in the users table.

Now my doubt is, why can't the `photos.id` be referenced to `users.id` in the photos table like `FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users(id)`, instead of how it was done in the course like `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)`? Can it be done like that? Why was a separate user_id created in photos table, instead of `photos.id` directly referencing to the `user.id` in the `users` table?

P.S: Apologies if the way I asked the question wasn't efficient.

[This was how it was done in the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38spq.png)

[Why can't it be done like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ9X7.png)

Comment: In future questions on Stack Overflow, please post code samples as text, not as screenshots. There are good reasons for this, please read them here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

Only one row in the photos table can have a given value for `id`. That is, being the primary key, every value in `id` must be unique in the photos table.

A foreign key must have the same value as the column in the other table it references.

So if you were to design the table as you suggest, making `id` the foreign key in photos as well as the primary key of that table, then only one row in photos could reference a given user.

But presumably, in an Instagram-like application, users should be allowed to have multiple photos.

The only way the user's multiple photos can reference that user who owns them, and also have a primary key that is unique, is to store a separate attribute column in the photos table, that is permitted to be non-unique. That is, multiple rows have the same value for `user_id`.

Comment: I got my doubt clarified. Thank you! Also yes, I will post code samples as text from next time, my apologies for the inconvenience.